# CounterStrike: GO - Xbox 360 controller not moving

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, counter-strike-global-offensive

I enabled the controller in the settings but I am unable to move in-game using the control sticks. This controller works with most other games that have controller support on steam.

Comment: Voters, please remember to leave a comment when voting to close as unclear if you believe there is important information the question is lacking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Against my better judgement I'm going to answer this and hope that one day you play this with the mouse and keyboard.

1. **Run** Steam in "Big Picture" mode, which is Steam's attempt at making their interface more console friendly.  (See bottom of post for information on how to activate Big Picture)
2. **Start** a game of CSGO, choose your team and open up your console (~). (See bottom of post for info on how to activate your developer console if you haven't already done so).
3. **Type** the command: "exec controller.360.cfg", hit enter.
4. **Type** the command: "joystick 1", hit enter.

This should allow you to play CSGO with the 360 controller.

**To activate Big Picture mode** you need to look at the top right corner of your Steam pgoram and find the button that - you guessed it - looks like a video game controller.  Click that then use the new-look Steam you've just activated to browse to your games and launch CSGO.

**If you don't already have the console activated** (you hit the ~ key and it doesn't open the developer console) you need to go to: Options>Game Settings and set "Enable Developer Console (~)" to "Yes".

Comment: I understand that CS is meant to be played with a mouse but, the game itself has settings to handle a controller. I really don't get why questions like this are almost never answered properly.

Comment: Seriously. Have your own opinions, but "against my better judgement I'm going to answer this...", really?

Comment: @TheAce I imagine that the developers want to encourage people to use mouse and keyboard by making it difficult to play using a controller. It's not impossible, but merely difficult.

Answer (score 6):

As someone with over 1,000 hours on CS GO with an Xbox 360 controller, I can tell you that you do not need to run `joystick 1` or run steam in "Big Picture" mode for a controller to work.

The file `controller.360.cfg` already contains the line `joystick 1` for you. (Although from my experience, CS:GO ignores this and still logs stats as KB/M)

All you have to do, is <strike>make sure your controller is plugged in before you start CS:GO, then</strike> *(this was fixed in an update)* when you're starting a game, open the developer console and type in `exec controller.360.cfg`. 
Your best bet is to make yourself an [autoexec.cfg file](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=166699655) that will automatically set up your preferred layout each time you join a game.

Comment: how do you navigate the main menu to find a game using the controller?  i could only do this with a mouse

Comment: @FistOfFury, I don't think the game supports this natively. However, you could reasonably find a program that lets you move the mouse and click using the controller which should allow full navigation and game starting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is quite simple.

1. Go into Steam "Big Picture Mode"
2. Run CSGO from there
3. Navigate to **Settings** --> **Controller**
4. Make sure Controller Enabled is set to **Enabled**
5. Connect your Xbox 360 controller and make sure that steam recognizes it(you can do this in **Settings** --> **Controller** in Steam Big Picture Mode)
6. Go back to **Settings** and click **Controller**, which will open up a steam interface which lets your control exactly what each input does in the game

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually so easy. At the home screen go into options and then press controller. Then press enable. This worked for me.

Comment: Didn't for me, not sure how it worked for you.