# mac osx 10 xbox 360 controller Counter strike GO

Tags: controllers, counter-strike-global-offensive, macos

So I got my xbox 360 controller working on my mac which actually took a while too

My controller will work with an old version of counterstrike (source), but not the new counterstrike go.

I searched all around, found some tips here but was dated last year
so not sure if those fixes still work.

I tried the console exec controller 360 command that you can find here in a search but it doesn't recognize the command. I do have the console turned on, and controller selected in the menu. I even tried the big picture mode some have said in the past to turn on. I've watched a few videos but I don't think they were with OS X 10

Any suggestions? I can't get the controller to work at all with CSGO, but it works with CS source, which is a very old game. I think the even older CS original game also won't work with the controller, but I'm fine with it not working with that one, and I have not tried any other games, only because I don't want to play those.

Comment: What version of OSX are you running?

Comment: its a brand new mac mini, I'm assuming Yosemite ?  really don't know how to even look up what I have. but there are no updates needed to the os if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried both of the below commands?

1. Start a game of CSGO, choose your team and open up your console (~).
2. Type the command: "exec controller.360.cfg", hit enter.
3. Type the command: "joystick 1", hit enter.

More insight may be found here: [CounterStrike: GO - Xbox 360 controller not moving](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209612/counterstrike-go-xbox-360-controller-not-moving)